# System.Web.Http.Cors: How to disable CORS request for a Web Api method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors

I have CORS setup with System.Web.Http.Cors (Nightly builds). Everything is working fine, until if I want to disable a CORS support for a method then iam not able to do so. A POST method of mine having [DisableCors] attribute above it is hit by debugger and data in posted in database. But the only good point in that is, the response ends with error (shown in firebug).

I dont want the method to save data when the request is from cross origin. It should filter it out from methods top only (like Authorize attribute in MVC).

Your help would be good support factor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For a simple HTTP requests (basically GET and POST with form-url-encoded) the request still executes on the server, but the client is not allowed access to the results. CORS (in this scenario) only indicates back to the browser if the client is allowed to consume the results.